# foreman register changes only after restart

Tags: foreman

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Foreman not reflecting changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10634944/foreman-not-reflecting-changes)

Can anyone please help me fix this problem:

- foreman register changes only after restart

What do I need to do that foreman registers changes when I refresh my page