# Foreman not reflecting changes

Tags: foreman

I used this article to set up the development environment for facebook app development:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook#create_an_app
Everything works great except FOREMAN:
The problem is - every time I make a change in my scripts, and when I want to see those changes locally - Foreman is not reflecting those changes. It "sees" changes only after I restart it.
Anyone encountered the same situation or knows what's the problem? If yes - help, please.

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question.